# How do I add to and update a many to many relationship in Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, ios8

I have a two core data models set-up that have a many-to-many relationship.

```
class BuddyCD: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var memberOfBunches: NSSet
}

class BunchCD: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var bunchMembers: NSSet
}
```

Sidenote: CD means Core Data here
I when creating a BunchCD, I would like to add many buddies to it as members.

I have this method in the Bunch class:

```
class func createInManagedObjectContext (moc: NSManagedObjectContext, members: [BuddyCD]?) -> BunchCD {

    let newBunch = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(CoreDataConst.bunchModel, inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! BunchCD

    if let membersNonOptional = members {
        // Add members to this bunch

        for member in membersNonOptional {
            member.addToBunch(newBunch)
        }
    }
    return newBunch
}
```

I have this method in the Buddy class:

```
func addToBunch(bunch: BunchCD) {
    var bunches = self.mutableSetValueForKey("memberOfBunches")
    bunches.addObject(bunch)
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
2015-07-19 01:00:38.587 MyApp[34979:1885727] -[__NSSetIobjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb7d3ecde30 2015-07-19 01:00:38.603 LunchBunch[34979:1885727] ***Terminating app due to uncaught exception'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSSetI objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb7d3ecde30'
```

What is the best practice for adding members to a many to many relationship in core data?

Comment: From what I've been taught - _many-to-many_ is not a good approach, you should try to create an intermediary Table that would connect both of them with _one-to-many_ connection. (e.g. Customer and Product tables would need a Transaction table to be connected properly...)

Comment: @IslamQ. No, many-to-many is the recommended way. You should only have a "join" table if the connection itself needs to store additional data.

Comment: @Mundi I agree, thanks for confirming... It just doesn't seem that easy or commonly used in Swift based on the lack of tutorial for many-to-many relationships... do you know any good ones?

Comment: I do not see the need for such tutorials. I usually just read the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the error originated elsewhere, I'm guessing from multi-threaded components of my application (that were not intentional).  The errors most likely stemmed from using Alamofire asynchronous requests and using the Managed Object Context in the request callbacks.  So, I added code around the Managed Object Context accesses to ensure it (the MOC) was being used on the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    // Managed Object Context access here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems OK. The error must originate elsewhere. Perhaps you can find out where by stepping through the code.